# How to connect directly to a database with mongosh

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, mongo-shell

I'm having connection problems with my local mongodb instance. Its not that it is not working, but there are some things that don't work, which I expected to work.

In my case I'm trying to setup my NestJS app with mongo ([this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/connecting-to-mongodb-c8166e0a6cb7)). It states at some point:

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/blog')
```

In my case it would be

```
MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://admin:admin@0.0.0.0:27017/blog')
```

Now whatever I do, it will not connect as long as I have the database name in that string.

I can reproduce this problem with `mongosh` too

```
$> mongosh mongodb://admin:admin@0.0.0.0:27017/blog
Current Mongosh Log ID: 640c5eeaaf2a65c11a7dda25
Connecting to:      mongodb://<credentials>@0.0.0.0:27017/blog? directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.8.0
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
```

But when I remove the database name it works (also in my NestJs app). I'm not very familiar with Mongo, so maybe I'm missing the point completely, but I think this should work and you have to connect to a database before you can do anything. So my question is, what am I doing wrong here? Any help would be apprecited!

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address, try using 127.0.0.1

Comment: IP-Address `0.0.0.0` means "all possible IP addresses". Try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `[::1]` or even better the hostname of your machine. And then [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470) could be relevant

Comment: when I change it to 127.0.0.1 I get the following error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jeanluca/blog'

Comment: If I try `mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/blog?authSource=admin` I get an error too: `zsh: no matches found: mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/blogs?authSource=admin`.  Maybe mongosh works differently on a mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use connection string like this :

mongosh **"mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017/mybase"** **--authenticationDatabase admin**

This will connect directly to your database **(mybase)** , and your user, pwd will be checked on ***admin*** db

Answer (score 1):

if you use Mongoose, you can add a specific database at the end of url and add authSorce as admin. example:

```
connection-string/specific-database?authSource=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already lunched mongosh, you are already in, you can use the `connect()` function

```
connect("<connection string>")
```